# why mssql_connect() not found

Tags: php, sql-server, database, eclipse

I have installed mssql server, php, Apache server, and Eclipse on my pc. I am trying to connect to a mssql database using mssql_connect(). I get this message:

> "Fatal error:function not found mssql_connect()"

I tried to place php_mssql.dll in the apache/bin but nothing seems to work.
I have configured my php.ini file.

1. Where is this file supposed to be placed?
2. Why does the fatal error happen?

Comment: Have you read this page? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.setup.php

Comment: What stack are you running? XAMPP?

Answer (score 2):

In the php.ini file, look for the `extension_dir` line.

Make sure that the php_mssql.dll file is in that directory, and also make sure to add the line:

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

Apart from that, read the third post down on this page:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

U have to place it into ur php extensions folder (look extension_dir in ur php.ini). and also add `extension=php_mssql.dll` to ur php.ini